# How to use an AngularjS View (.html file) without using it's tags

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing, angular-controller, angular-template

Inside a big AngularJS application I have a new HTML template file and a controller for it, and I'd like to build a layout the designer gave me using this temporary view, since I'd like to be able to call some data from the $scope object.

I also created a new route for it so that I have a clean working space.

But I don't want to include it in the main index.html file, like so:

```
<my-new-template></my-new-template>
```

I'd just like to start using it without having to include this HTML element anywhere, is this possible? This is the controller so far:

```
.directive('portfolio', [
function () {
        return {
            templateUrl: "views/temporary-view.html",
            scope: {
                data: "="
            },

            link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {                  
                scope.stuff = 'stuff';                  
            }
        };
    }])
```

The view:

```
<nav class="portfolio-view">
       {{stuff}}
</nav>
```

Thanks for helping a noob like me! :)

Comment: Really sorry to see already you got some down vote. It would be great if the person who downvoted could have left a comment for you. Basically, your question is not clear. For Example, you are showing a directive code as controller code. Maybe you need to rephrase the entire question, so that you can get response from community.

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying, in other words use .controller instead of .directive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I just changed .directive to .controller and posted it alongside the other controllers in the app and not the directives... I guess I was confused with that!

```
.controller('PortfolioView', ["$scope",
    function ($scope) {
        $scope.stuff = 'stuff'; 
    }])
```

Answer (score 1):

In your directive, you can change the `restrict` option to change how the directive is called in the HTML. There are 4 options for this. I found this in the [AngularJS documentation for directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#directive-definition-object):

```
restrict
String of subset of EACM which restricts the directive to a specific directive declaration style. If omitted, the defaults (elements and attributes) are used.

E - Element name (default): <my-directive></my-directive>
A - Attribute (default): <div my-directive="exp"></div>
C - Class: <div class="my-directive: exp;"></div>
M - Comment: <!-- directive: my-directive exp -->
```

By default, it uses `EA`, so as an Element (the way you do not want to call it in HTML) or an attribute.

If you wish to change it to, say, class for example, then change your directive definition to:

```
.directive('portfolio', [
function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'C',
            templateUrl: "views/temporary-view.html",
            scope: {
                data: "="
            },

            link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {                  
                scope.stuff = 'stuff';                  
            }
        };
    }])
```

and you can call it as so:

`<div class="portfolio"></div>`

I think this is what you mean, and I hope it helps!